# MySQL insert where does not exist not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a MySQL insert query only if it doesn't already exist. This is how i'm trying it but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO user_logs (log_date, log_ip, name) VALUES ('2021-09-13 00:00:00', '192.168.0.1', 'Bob') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE log_ip='192.168.0.1' AND name='Bob')
```

Comment: yes as inserts don't have a where clasue

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement. However, you can use a `SELECT` statement within an `INSERT` that will allow you to use a `WHERE` conditional.

```sql
INSERT INTO user_logs (log_date, log_ip, name) 
SELECT '2021-09-13 00:00:00', '192.168.0.1', 'Bob'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE log_ip = '192.168.0.1' AND name = 'Bob');
```

---

Edit: I've included below test statements and console output to demonstrate this solution.

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE user_logs (
    ->     log_date TIMESTAMP,
    ->     log_ip VARCHAR(200),
    ->     name VARCHAR(200)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO user_logs (log_date, log_ip, name) VALUES
    -> ('2021-09-11 00:00:00', '192.168.0.1', 'Bob'),
    -> ('2021-09-12 00:00:00', '192.168.0.2', 'Mary'),
    -> ('2021-09-13 00:00:00', '192.168.0.3', 'Tom');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO user_logs (log_date, log_ip, name) 
    -> SELECT '2021-09-14 00:00:00', '192.168.0.4', 'John'
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE log_ip = '192.168.0.4' AND name = 'John');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO user_logs (log_date, log_ip, name) 
    -> SELECT '2021-09-13 00:00:00', '192.168.0.3', 'Tom'
    -> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_logs WHERE log_ip = '192.168.0.3' AND name = 'Tom');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Just tried this but I get an error saying SYNTAX error on line that reads WHERE NOT EXISTS

Comment: That line is copied from your query and the full statement works when tested on my end. I'll edit my answer with console outputs to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

if log_ip  and name are UNIQUE  YOu can use ON DUPLICATE UPDATE

This would update the column log_date if name and log_ip dare the same

```
INSERT INTO user_logs (log_date, log_ip, name) VALUES ('2021-09-13 00:00:00', '192.168.0.1', 'Bob') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  log_date = VALUES(log_date),log_ip = VALUES(log_ip), name = VAUES(name) ;
```